# Email validation in Javascript for a specific scenario

Tags: javascript, email-validation

I have tried approximately all the regex solution but I am still able to bypass the validation for the below email -

> test_test_test@yaho..co.uk

I need to mark this email as invalid using `Javascript`. Please share the correct regex that I can use to mark above email as invalid.

Comment: Show us *all the regex solution* you tried

Comment: /^[\w_\-\.\d]+@([\w_\-\d]+\.)+[\w_\-\d]{2,5}$/

Comment: ... and rest suggested by Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this one](https://regex101.com/library/uZ1uB4) from Regex101

I think your previous regex might accidentally include `\.` inside character list with `+` quantifier, so `@xx..co` still can be bypass

```js
var regex = /^[0-9a-zA-Z-_\$#]+@[0-9a-zA-Z-_\$#]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}/;
console.log(regex.test('test_test_test@yaho..co.uk'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

console.log(validateEmail("test_test_test@yaho..co.uk"));
console.log(validateEmail("test_test_test@yaho.co.uk"));
```